# Add a list of paths permanently to Matlab path programmatically

Tags: matlab

I'm switching between Matlab versions. However I have a huge list of custom paths which I would need to move to the new version.

Has anyone an idea how to do that?

It seems like the command

```
for i = 1:numPaths
    path(path,myPathList{i}) 
end
```

is only adding a path temporally. Also `addpath` is only making temporal changes for one matlab session only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`savepath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savepath.html) to save the path to a `pathdef.m` file which will persist between MATLAB sessions. Where this `pathdef.m` files lives is dependent upon your current configuration:

> `savepath` saves the current MATLAB® search path to an existing `pathdef.m` file in the current folder. If there is no `pathdef.m` file in the current folder, then `savepath` saves the search path to the first `pathdef.m` file on the current path. If there is no such file on the current path, then `savepath` saves the search path to the `pathdef.m` file that MATLAB located at startup.
>   On a Windows® system with User Account Control (UAC) enabled, you might be prompted to allow the update operation because it requires administrator-level permission.

```
% Add all paths in myPathList to the path
addpath(myPathList{:}) 

% Save it so that they are already added in new instances
savepath
```

**Update**

`savepath` located a `pathdef.m` file on the user's path; however, the startup directory of MATLAB was not that location since the application was launched from the command line so eventhough the altered path was saved to the `pathdef.m` file, it was not read in when the application launched. The solution was to remove this "local" `pathdef.m` so that the one within the installation directory was used instead.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work. Not even if I start Matlab with sudo  rights

Comment: The changes are not permanent. But it's really strange since even using the gui to add a folder path is not permanent. Maybe it's a bug of Matlab 2014a...

Comment: @mcExchange What does `which('pathdef.m')` give you?

Comment: `/home/myUsername/Documents/MATLAB/pathdef.m`

Comment: @mcExchange If you open that file does it look like it was modified by the above commands? Also, are you sure `myPathList` contains the paths you're expecting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121550/discussion-between-mcexchange-and-suever).

Comment: @mcExchange Added an updated section with the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck, I had to deal with the exact problem at work where people would keep switching between verisions of MATLAB and a saved path can cause trouble in some cases. I wrote a small function to go in my startup.m which makes sure that all the custom paths are added on top of the default path for the particular version of MATLAB in use. Note that I am assuming that MATLAB exists in C:\Program Files, you can change it as per your need.

```
function setPathForNewVersion()
% Find all path strings which do not belong to toolbox folders
customFolders = regexp(strsplit(path,';'),...
    '^(?!C:\\Program Files(\s\(x86\))?\\MATLAB\\R\d{4}(?:a|b)\\toolbox\\\S*)(.*)','match');
customFolderCells = [customFolders{cellfun(@(x)~isempty(x),customFolders)}]; % Remove empty cells

restoredefaultpath; % Momentarily
newPath = sprintf('%s;',customFolderCells{:});
path(newPath, path); % Add the user's custom path to the top
savepath;
end
```

In your startup.m then you can have

```
function startup
setPathForNewVersion();
end
```

Comment: So this function is called everytime Matlab is starting up? That would mean that I have to place the function `setPathForNewVersion` in some default Matlab path? I'm really surprised why one cannot simply store these entries permanently instead of calling them on every startup... Maybe its a bug in Matlab 2014a ...

Comment: If you are not switching between versions and this is a one time transition then its fine to use `savepath` but if you frequently go from one version to another it is better to be doing this every time in startup. And you can add `setPathForNewVersion` as a sub function in your `startup.m`